# mysql union change values

Tags: mysql, union-all

I want to add the columns names in the result of my query.

with:

```
select MYVALUE from MYTABBLE;
```

I obtain

```
+---------+
| MYVALUE |
+---------+
|    0.70 |
+---------+
```

with

```
select 'value' union all select MYVALUE from MYTABBLE;
```

I obtain

```
+--------------+
|    value     |
+--------------+
|    value     |
| 0.6999999881 |
+--------------+
```

I'm sure 0.70 is the right value.

MYVALUE is a float.

Why does it change ? how can i get the good value ?

**EDIT :**  It's indeed a float/string problem. I solved with :

```
select 'value' union all select CAST(MYVALUE AS CHAR)from MYTABBLE;
```

Comment: `'value'` is not a number - it's a String. And one that can't be converted to a number. I'm surprised that MySQL actually allows this statement to run. In a `union` each column from each union part must have exactly the same data type. Postgres and Oracle would simply refuse to run this. You are mixing strings and numbers. No wonder you are getting some weird values (MySQL is known to do a lot of weird conversions in order to avoid an error message at any cost)

Comment: Oh and btw: you most probably do **not** want a `float` column: http://floating-point-gui.de/